# Evaluating truthy values

Tags: mysql, truthiness

I wanted to say something like:

```
 if field_1 then set field_2 = 1
```

Meaning, if field_1 holds a truthy value, do something else. Can an IF statement in sql execute this kind of evaluation?

Comment: What should `field_2` be set to otherwise - if `field_1` is falsy?

Comment: @RocketHazmat I guess my question just has to do more with whether or not I can make a truthy evaluation, and not the syntax of an if then else statement.

Comment: You could try it with the [`IF()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if).  Something like: `SET field_2 = IF(field_1, 1, 0)`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat interesting, I'll check that now.

Comment: have you just tried a simple google search for this? there are plenty of results!! :)

Comment: @LelioFaieta I have googled "truthy values" extensively. Not a lot of material.

Comment: @LelioFaieta not a duplicate because my question has nothing to do with output columns and everything to do with a truthy evaluation.

Comment: Maybe "MySQL if statements "? Or "MySQL conditional statements "?

Comment: @LelioFaieta this has nothing to do with conditional statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CASE WHEN THEN` and set field2 to 1 if the CASE WHEN is true, else use  `ELSE` to set field2 to what it was before.

```
UPDATE table 
SET field2 = CASE
WHEN field1 IS NOT NULL 
THEN 1
ELSE field2
END;
```

Comment: this is a really nice way to do this, and I was familiar with IS NOT NULL, so I guess you can't make a truthy evaluation?

Comment: Everything but null is true in mysql @JosephErickson

Comment: @JosephErickson if you wan't to check against the string `true` or `1`, simply replace `is not null` with `=1` or `='true'`